# Is there a lightweight web server with CGI support?

Tags: http, webserver, cgi

I have to work on a small CGI script that needs to be in C/C++. Instead of compiling and installing to a system directory (like `/var/www/cgi-bin`), I'd like to be able to execute it from my development directory. I tried using `php -S localhost:8080` but it doesn't appear that PHP's built-in web server supports CGI binaries.

This is what I want to do:

```
# Go to source directory and compile program.cgi
cd ~/projects/cgi
make
# Start the web server and open a browser.
web-server localhost:8080
google-chrome http://localhost:8080/program.cgi
```